# Converting zoo to ts before forecasting

Tags: r, time-series, zoo

I am struggling to convert a `zoo` objects to a `ts` object.

I have a huge data.frame "test" with quarterly hour data, which looks like this:

```
date <- c("2010-07-04 09:45:00", "2010-07-04 10:00:00", "2010-07-04 10:15:00", "2010-07-04 10:30:00", "2010-07-04 10:45:00", "2010-07-04 11:00:00")
nrv <- c("-147.241", "-609.778", "-432.289", "-340.418", "-73.96" ,  "-533.108")
tt <- c("3510.7", "3608.5", "3835.7", "4003.7", "4018.8", "4411.9")
test <- data.frame(date,nrv,tt)
test
```

I want to make some predictions (mostly `ARIMA`) and thought the `forecast`package would be a good idea for that.
First of I formated the data away from characters.

```
test$date <- strptime(test$date,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
test$nrv <- as.numeric(as.character(test$nrv))
test$tt <- as.numeric(as.character(test$tt))
str(test) #date is POSIXlt object
```

Since I needed to do an interpolation and construct lags, I also used the `zoo` package using the date variable as index, which worked great. The `` `zoo `` package was recommended to me while dealing with time series data.

```
library(zoo)
test.zoo <- zoo(test[,2:3],test[,1])
test.zoo #date is now the Index and and the zoo objects works nicely
```

But then I realized that forecasting only seems to work with `ts` objects. (Is that true?)

When I tried to convert the `zoo` object to a `ts` object, my time index disappeared. I think this might be due to not using a proper frequency. However I am somewhat lost as to what would be a working frequency for this dataset and with `ts` objects in general.

```
test.ts <- as.ts(test.zoo)
test.ts
```

How do I convert this `zoo` object back to a `ts` object I can use for forecasting?
Thanks!

Comment: At the very beginning, yes. But later test$date is changed. In `str(test.zoo)` it is correctly shown as POSIXlt.

Comment: `methods(forecast)` shows which classes work with the `forecast` function.

Answer (score 3):

The forecast package only works with `ts` objects as you suspected.

You can use `test.ts` with the forecast package. For example

```
plot(forecast(test.ts[,1]))
```

Comment: As I had still trouble dealing with the `ts` objects I simply converted it to a `xts` objects which kept the date information in the Index.
While dealing with forecasting I dropped the date information in the Index altogether using `coredata()`. That way I could still quite easily subset the data and make use of the forecasting commands.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and solved it by using zooreg function.
step1: use zooreg to transform zoo object to non-zoo but ts alike objet 
step2: use ts function to transform further to ts object